# Настройка ЧПУ для frontend и backend

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii2

Использую Yii 2 Advanced. Сколько ни смотрю решения - всё сводится к виду адресной строки: `http://localhost:8888/yii2-app-advanced/backend/web/mytable/create`.

Хочется такого:

`yii2-app-advanced` - корень frontend

`yii2-app-advanced/admin` - корень backend

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Сейчас описано, что хочется, но что не получается - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этого можно добиться средствами веб-сервера (у апача через алиас, например). При этом физическая структура файлов того же адвансед-примера останется неизменной.
Насколько я понимаю вам нужно примерно так в апаче:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/yii2-app-advanced/frontend/web/
Alias /admin /var/www/yii2-app-advanced/backend/web/
```

Comment: ну вот в первом yii через htacces правилось и urlmanager. здесь нужно явно лезть в апач? и можно более полный ответ

Comment: В yii1 весь фреймворк был наружу и что надо закрывалось через тот самый htaccess, во втором подразумевается, что наружу торчит только входной скрипт и статика, а весь код находится вне веб-рута. Отсюда дефолтная структура адвансед приложения, где две точки входа для фронт- и бекенда находятся на одном уровне в плане файловой структуры, а не вложены друг в друга. Дописал пример с апачем в ответ.